# What am I supposed to see on tensorboard images tab?

Tags: tensorflow, training, object-detection, model-evaluations

I'm training an object detection model with Tensorflow and monitor the training task with tensorboard. I was expecting in the Images tab of tensorboard that displayed images would show a bounding box (at a specific point of training). What I see though is only images with an orange line drawn above the picture (the same orange that I expect for the bounding box). Am I missing something? Am I right when I say that a bounding box should appear or not? Picture of what I see is joined. Any help greatly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see using data from Pascal VOC that was converted using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/2bde248588c8388f9d6cd4d48712ff9ca52d6288/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pascal_tf_record.py) example script: [image: Images from Tensorboard]

I am using Tensorflow 2. I think it's just the images preprocessed using the `data_augmentation_options` that were specified in your pipeline.config file.

I seem to recall seeing bounding boxes on the images in Tensorboard back when I was using the Object Detection API with Tensorflow 1. But I haven't seen any bounding boxes on the images using the API with Tensorflow 2. I have verified that the models subsequently worked. I just didn't see bounding boxes in Tensorboard. Note that I am just running training and then doing evaluation separately. If you specified eval_config or eval_input_reader in your pipeline.config, you might get different results.